# Validating login page - return to homepage if password is correct, if not stay on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up a registration page where the details are all saved to local storage in the browser. When the user is told to login using the registered details, they must be redirected to the homepage if the validation is successful.

Validation is working fine and i am getting system feedback if the password is wrong for example. I am not quite sure how i can be taken to the homepage ONLY if the password is correct.

Full code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<link href ="styles.css" type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>

<!--     Header-->
     <div id="header"> 
      <button type="button" class="button">Basket</button>
     </div>

<!--    Main Login Form-->
     <div class="SignLog"><h2>Sign up or Log in</h2></div>
      <body onload="checkLogin()">

     <div id="loginPara" class="login">
     <form id="login" action = index.html onsubmit="return false">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="userid" id="emailin"><br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Create a password" name="pswrd" id=passwordin><br>
         <input type="button" onclick="login()" value="Login" id="loginbutton"/>
         <p>-------------------------- or----------------------------</p>
         <a href="register.html">  <input type="button"  value="Register" id="registerbutton"/> </a>
         <br>
         <p>By continuing you agree to our <a>T&Cs</a>. Please also check out our <a>Privacy Policy</a>. We use your data to offer you a personalised experience and to better understand and improve our services. For more information <a>see here</a>.</p>
         </form>

          <div id="loginFailure" style="color:red;"><p></p>
          </div>

         </div>

<!--          LOCAL STORAGE IS CHECKED TO SEE IF USER IS REGISTERED.-->
          <script>

         function checkLogin() {

             if(localStorage.loggedinUsrEmail !== undefined) {

                 var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedinUsremail]);

                 document.getElementById("loginPara").innerHTM = usrObj.firstName + " logged in."

             }
         }

        function login() {

            var email = document.getElementById("emailin").value;

            if(localStorage[email] === undefined){

                document.getElementById("loginFailure").innerHTML = "Email not recognized" ;
                return;
            }

            else{
                var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[email]);
                var password = document.getElementById("passwordin").value;

                if(password === usrObj.password) {
                    document.getElementById("loginPara").innerHTML =usrObj.firstname + " logged in.";
                    document.getElementById("loginFailure").innerHTML = "";
                    localStorage.loggedinUsrEmail =usrObj.email;

                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("loginFailure").innerHTML = "Password incorrect.";
                }

            }

        }



         </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect you can use:

```
if (password === usrObj.password) {
    window.location = "https://example.com";
}
```

Please be aware, that checking passwords in the browser gives you no security.